# unique_ptr, make_unique and polymorphism

Tags: c++

Would not `make_unique` be more useful if it was designed like:

```
template< typename T, typename U=T, typename ...ArgT>
unique_ptr<T> make_unique( ArgT ...args )
{
    return unique_ptr<T>( new U(args...) );
    // maybe parameters should be forwarded, not really important for this question
}
```

So that you could use it to create derived objects? 
Anyone know the rational behind not doing this?

Comment: Could you demonstrate how this would work, and how it would be better than just doing it normally?

Comment: it would work like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbfe9282c01a575e

Comment: and the point is to never type `new`

Comment: @tadman `auto = make_unique<Foo, Bar>()` creates an instance of `Foo` and returns `unique_ptr<Bar>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because  there's no point, you can just do the conversion after calling it anyway.

```
std::unique_ptr<T> p = std::make_unique<U>(args);
```

So if there's a function that takes `std::unique_ptr<T>` you can still do

```
func(std::make_unique<U>(args));
```

For your live example, you can just do:

```
the_list.push_back( make_unique<Child>(1) );
```

What's the benefit of your suggestion?  It just seems like more typing for no reason.

(Also, in general this isn't safe as it assumes the base class has a virtual destructor, you need to be careful about converting `unique_ptr` objects, so having a `make_unique` that encourages it might be risky.)

Comment: did not know they converted silently. should have tried that.

Comment: There's an implicit conversion from `unique_ptr<U, E>` to `unique_ptr<T, D>` if `U*` is implicitly convertible to `T*` and `E` is implicitly convertible to `D`

Answer (score 0):

You will find that std::unique_ptr can move from derived's to base's, if you look into its definition. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797286/3758879