# "No viable function" when attempting to insert pair<string, Derived*> into unordered_map<string, Base*>

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I am getting a red underlined segment of code in Visual Studio 2017 with resharper when I try to insert a unique_ptr to a derived class into an unordered_map of my base class. I specifically say a "red underlined segment" because the code still compiles and seems to run, but I am worried that I am doing something incorrect.

Here is the base class.

```
class irc_message_handler
{
public:
    irc_message_handler::irc_message_handler(user_map& users,
                                             channel_map& channels)
    virtual ~irc_message_handler() = default;
    virtual void handle(const irc_message& message) const = 0;

protected:
    user_map& users_;
    channel_map& channels_;
};
```

and the derived class:

```
class nick_handler
    : public irc_message_handler
{
public:
    nick_handler(user_map& users, channel_map& channels);
    void handle(const irc_message& message) const override;

private:
    void add_user(std::string nick) const;
    void update_user_nick(std::string nick, user_map::iterator user) const;
};
```

I am trying to add a unique_ptr of the derived class to an unordered_map like this.

```
using handler_map = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<irc_message_handler>>;

handler_map handlers_;

// No viable function. Argument types: '<unknown>'
handlers_.insert({ "NICK", std::make_unique<nick_handler>(users_, channels_) });
```

I do not get any red line if I try to make a unique_ptr to the base class.

```
handlers_.insert({ "NICK", std::make_unique<irc_message_handler>(users_, channels_) });
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Unfortunately even through a `derived` is a type of `base` and a pointer to `derived` can be interpreted as a pointer to `base`, the inheritance does not extend to objects containing `base`s and `derived`s. In other words `pair<string, derived *>` does not derive from `pair<string, base*>` and the two are not compatible. You will have to force the `derived *` into a `pair<string, base *>` to make the `pair` fit. Fortunately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996161/unique-ptr-make-unique-and-polymorphism suggests that you should be able to do this by adding an extra step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unique\_ptr, make\_unique and polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996161/unique-ptr-make-unique-and-polymorphism)